# What is the purpose of using a random integer in the attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was recently given a chunk of code to maintain. I have limited front-end experience but the use of

```
    let rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 9999999999);
```

and

```
    checkbox.setAttribute('data-id', rand);
```

appeared odd.

Function in question:

```
/**
** Cancel edits in Panel
**
**/
cancel( scope ) {
    console.log("--------------------------------");
    console.log("Synapse: checkbox");
    let self = this;

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        let rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 9999999999);
        let checkbox = document.createElement('i');
        checkbox.className = "fal fa-square checkbox";
        checkbox.setAttribute('data-id', rand);

        $('input[type="checkbox"]').parent().on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).find('[data-fa-processed]').hasClass('fa-check-square')) {
                $('#' + $(checkbox).data('id')).prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $('#' + $(checkbox).data('id')).prop('checked', true);
            }
            $(this)
            .find('[data-fa-processed]')
            .toggleClass('fa-check-square')
            .toggleClass('fa-square');
        }).addClass('checkbox-parent');
        $(this).attr('id', rand).hide().before(checkbox);
    });
    // On click, select the hidden checkbox and change the square to a check-square
}
```

Comment: It just looks like the original dev wanted to add an `id` to the checkbox should it ever need it. Without knowing the larger context of the code, it would appear to be a code smell (as DOM traversal is a much better technique) and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a way the developer found to give an "unique" identifier for each checkbox icon `<i>`. It hides the checkbox and display an icon instead and relate each other with the "rand" number. (`id` property in checkbox and `data-id` property in the icon).

The unique identifier is added so he can make reference for it.

For me, this is a bad approach (I agree with [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan)):

1. Ok, he is using a random with a big number... But, would never be two id's with same value?! That can happen.
2. The on click event is being added inside a forEach loop. Probably this event is being created many times. That could lead to misbehaviours.
3. He could make use of the position of the  he has created in relation to the checkbox and the parent. I think that, this way, it would be possible to update and toggle classes when needed without the data-id.